# Custom elements not sizing properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, custom-element

I've created a custom element to handle some data passing, which it does perfectly. At this point, I'd like to add some styling to enable my custom elements to act kind of like divs. Specifically, I've got a table in one of them, and I don't want it growing down the page as I add data to it.

Right now, my html looks kind of like this:

```
<head>
  <script>
    var myProto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
    myProto.method = function(){};

    document.register('my-element', {prototype: myProto});
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <my-element>
    <table>
      <tr><td>Foo</td><td>Bar</td><tr>
      <tr><td>Foo</td><td>Bar</td><tr>
      <tr><td>Foo</td><td>Bar</td><tr>
      <tr><td>Foo</td><td>Bar</td><tr>
    </table>
  </my-element>

  <script>/*Other Code*/</script>
</body>
```

I'd like to style it so that I can specify something like this css:

```
my-element{
  height : 200px;
  overflow-x : scroll;
}
```

The problem is that the custom elements don't seem to size to fit around their contents, so nothing with `height` or `overflow` is affecting them.

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ynreuka1/2/)

Comment: No need for the 's in css.

Comment: Too used to styling stuff in the javascript :) Fixed the css and added a fiddle based on @HakurHaf's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just style it like any other element.  Your CSS syntax is invalid.

Try this:

```
my-element {
  height:200px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

My own working sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/ynreuka1/

**UPDATE:**  Your custom element is not a block level element.  Add `display:block;` and then it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/ynreuka1/3/

**Yet another update**, with specific dimensions and scrollbars:

http://jsfiddle.net/ynreuka1/4/

Comment: I guess I have a different issue than I though. The problem seems to be that the custom elements aren't sizing to fit their contents, and hence any scroll bars aren't working. I've modified your fiddle and it shows this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/ynreuka1/1/